# Are within codeblock imports costly in scala

Tags: performance, scala

Sometimes it is convenient and clearer to use `import` statements to access multiple elements of an object.

For example, the code

```
x.y.z.a = 1
x.y.z.b = 2
x.y.z.c = 3
```

can be written as

```
{
    import x.y.z._

    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
}
```

obviously it is much more useful when the names are longer.

Is all the work done at compile time, or is the import statement executed at runtime in some way? Is there any cost, in efficiency or otherwise, to using this style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all names and implicits are resolved at compile time, and `import` doesn't affect anything else.

Of course, what gets executed is still

```
x.y.z.a = 1
x.y.z.b = 2
x.y.z.c = 3
```

so you'll fetch `x.y.z` 3 times (in this example). If `z` is

```
package x.y
object z { ... }
```

this is again just name resolution; but if instead you have something like

```
object x {
  val y = ... // some type which has val z
}
```

it's 2 method calls each time and putting `z` into a local variable performs better (but JIT may optimize this if this code runs often enough).

Answer (score 6):

You can check for yourself with `javap`. Start with something like this:

```
package x.y {
  object z {
    var a = "abc"
    var b = "def"
    var c = "ghi"
  }
}

object Test {
  def withImport: Unit = {
    import x.y.z._

    a = "zyx"
    b = "wvu"
    c = "rst"
  }

  def withoutImport: Unit = {
    x.y.z.a = "zyx"
    x.y.z.b = "wvu"
    x.y.z.c = "rst"
  }
}
```

Compile with `scalac Test.scala` and then `javap -c Test\$`:

```
  public void withImport();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: getstatic     #18                 // Field x/y/z$.MODULE$:Lx/y/z$;
         3: ldc           #20                 // String zyx
         5: invokevirtual #24                 // Method x/y/z$.a_$eq:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         8: getstatic     #18                 // Field x/y/z$.MODULE$:Lx/y/z$;
        11: ldc           #26                 // String wvu
        13: invokevirtual #29                 // Method x/y/z$.b_$eq:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        16: getstatic     #18                 // Field x/y/z$.MODULE$:Lx/y/z$;
        19: ldc           #31                 // String rst
        21: invokevirtual #34                 // Method x/y/z$.c_$eq:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        24: return
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      25     0  this   LTest$;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 13: 0
        line 14: 8
        line 15: 16

  public void withoutImport();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: getstatic     #18                 // Field x/y/z$.MODULE$:Lx/y/z$;
         3: ldc           #20                 // String zyx
         5: invokevirtual #24                 // Method x/y/z$.a_$eq:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         8: getstatic     #18                 // Field x/y/z$.MODULE$:Lx/y/z$;
        11: ldc           #26                 // String wvu
        13: invokevirtual #29                 // Method x/y/z$.b_$eq:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        16: getstatic     #18                 // Field x/y/z$.MODULE$:Lx/y/z$;
        19: ldc           #31                 // String rst
        21: invokevirtual #34                 // Method x/y/z$.c_$eq:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        24: return
        ...
```

Literally identical bytecode.